# Как вызвать функцию состоящую из пристыкованнных переменных?

Tags: php

на сервер приходят данные, которые в зависимости от значения одного из элементов массива нужно передать в разные функции. Чтобы не городить несоколько switch/case
хочу обращаться к функция так:

```
$data = array(
   'table' => 1,
   'sumArr' = array(.....);
);
myFoo.$data['table']($data);


function myFoo1($data){

}
function myFoo2($data){

}
.....
```

и что делать если код написано в ООП?
Вот так рботает:

```
$data = $this->_myfooOne($postdata);
```

А вот так уже нет:

```
$varfoo = $this->"_myfoo".$num;
$data = $varfoo($postdata);
```

пишет

> syntax error unexpected "_myfoo"

или так сделать не получится и значение элемента table нужно будет прокидывать как аргумент в одну большую функцию там уже работать?

все таки мне хотелось бы иметь несколько самостоятельных функций к которым если что я смогу обратиться напрямую..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для динамического вызова функции по имени (которое вы определяете программным путем) используйте [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php)

в вашем случае будет что-то вроде

```
$fname = "myFoo" . $data['table'];
$result = call_user_func($fname, $data);
```

В целом, конечно, хорошо бы проверить параметры на корректность (что в `$data['table']` у вас валидное значение), а также возможно убедиться, что такая функция определена, используя `function_exists($fname)`:

```
if(function_exists($fname)){
     call_user_func($fname, $data);
}
```

Хотя можно поступить и проще, используя ["переменные функции"](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php)

```
$fname = "myFoo" . $data['table'];
$result = $fname();
```

в случае если работа идет в контексте объекта, то в целом ничего не меняется

```
$fname = "myFoo" . $data['table'];
$result = $this->$fname($data);
```

в случае использования `call_user_func`, первым аргументом должно быть не просто имя функции, а массив содержащий адрес экземпляра объекта и имя функции), а-ля

```
call_user_func([$this, $fname], $data)
```

Comment: а что делать в случае с ООП? дополнил вопрос

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов не читали по ссылке, да? :) дополнил ответ

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов из вашего же примера можно было сделать так: `$varfoo = $this->{"_myfoo".$num};` - фигурные скобки

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'table'=>1,
    'sumArr' => array()
);

function myFoo1($data){
    print_r($data);
}

function myFoo2($data){
    print_r($data);
}
$function = 'myFoo'.$data['table'];
$function($data);
```